# Apple Photos: observing MLMediaGroup changes using MediaLibrary on macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to display Album structure of Apple Photos in my application on macOS. The only way to do it that I could find is MediaLibrary framework. I can traverse the tree structure using MLMediaGroup class without problems. But watching changes in it makes me puzzled. I would expect that I need to subscribe to KVO-notificatios for each individual media group and watch the changes in attributes.

But in reality when I create a new album/folder in Photos I get a notification that the rootMediaGroup has changed, and the addresses of this group as well as all child groups also change. This seems strange because now I have to rebuild the whole album-hierarchy. This is like watching directory changes and getting opaque notifications like "something in the filesystem has changed" without further details each time a user modifies a directory somewhere deep inside $HOME.

I'm using objective-c (in fact I need to integrate it with c++), although swift examples may also give me a hint. Below I provide a minimal example to illustrate the question.

PhotosObserver.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MediaLibrary/MediaLibrary.h>

@interface PhotosObserver: NSObject
{
    @private
    MLMediaLibrary *ml;
    MLMediaSource *src;
    MLMediaGroup *root;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain, nullable, readonly) MLMediaLibrary *ml;
@property(nonatomic, retain, nullable, readonly) MLMediaSource *src;
@property(nonatomic, retain, nullable, readonly) MLMediaGroup *root;

@end
```

PhotosObserver.m

```
#include "PhotosObserver.h"

static void* CTX_MEDIASOURCE         = &CTX_MEDIASOURCE;
static void* CTX_MEDIAGROUP          = &CTX_MEDIAGROUP;

static NSString* KPATH_SOURCES = @"mediaSources";
static NSString* KPATH_GROUPS  = @"rootMediaGroup";

@implementation PhotosObserver

@synthesize ml;
@synthesize src;
@synthesize root;

-(id)init {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self->ml = [[MLMediaLibrary alloc] init];
        [self->ml addObserver: self forKeyPath:KPATH_SOURCES options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:CTX_MEDIASOURCE];
        [self->ml mediaSources];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    @try {
        [self.ml removeObserver:self forKeyPath:KPATH_SOURCES context:CTX_MEDIASOURCE];
        [self.src removeObserver:self forKeyPath:KPATH_GROUPS context:CTX_MEDIAGROUP];
    }
    @catch(NSException *) {}
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if(CTX_MEDIASOURCE == context)
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded mediaSources");
        self->src = [self->ml.mediaSources objectForKey:/*@"com.apple.Photos"*/MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier];
        assert(self->src);
        [self.src addObserver: self forKeyPath:KPATH_GROUPS options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:CTX_MEDIAGROUP];
        [self.src rootMediaGroup];
    }
    else if(CTX_MEDIAGROUP == context)
    {
        MLMediaGroup *old = self->root;
        if(!old)
            NSLog(@"Loaded rootMediaGroup");
        self->root = self.src.rootMediaGroup;
        if(old && old != self.root)
        {
            NSLog(@"Oops, root group has changed: %@ -> %@", old, self.root);
        }
    }
}


@end
```

When I run the program and create a folder/album, or rename an album in Photos, I get a notification that the root group is changed. For some reason I don't get notifications in 100% of cases but anyway quite often.

Q: Why does rootMediaGroup get changed at all, since the user cannot change it in Photos UI?

Q: How to watch for the changes without the need to rescan the whole MLMediaGroup hierarchy after each small user modification?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As your question is currently worded, it results in being a "primarily opinion based" question. You should reword your question to be about a specific problem. For example, remove "what is the correct way" and similar language, and use "why do I not receive notifications 100% of case.." or similar language. Make sure to have your question be about a specific problem you're having. Otherwise, excellent job formatting and explaining your problem!

Comment: @Jack Thanks for the good hint. I did my best to re-phrase the question, but I cannot avoid the howto-part about the efficient way to watch for changes since it's the essence of this question. I cannot believe I should re-scan the whole hierarchy on each small change.